# Calls to multiple controllers in Sails.JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have an application with two tables: employee and department.
In my employee controller, I have a create function to generate an employee.
Similarly, in my department table, I have a create function to generate a department. Now, whenever I get a request to generate an employee, I have to insert my create employee function in both tables. My request first routes to the employee controller where I make an insert into the employee table. From here, what should I call the controller for the department table?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Standalone Actions? Sails has this for issues with multiple actions in a single controller file. In a Standalone Action, each action is in its own in a 
 subfolder of api/controllers such as

```
api/
 controllers/
  user/
   login.js
   logout.js
   signup.js
```

From the Official SailsJS Actions and Controllers - Full Document Here: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers